# How do make a query with Entity key and sort it to App Engine datastore in Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've been programming an app which uses GAE and I store the entities with a specific Key depending on the user nick logged in Google.

The problem is that I can't make a query that retrieves the entities with a specific key and sort the entities retrieved by whatever too.

I'll give some examples:

```
Query query = new Query("Invoice", key);
//This works; retrieved all entities that have the key

Query query = new Query("Invoice").addSort("Date", Query.SortDirection.ASCENDING);
//This works too, retrieves ALL entities sorted by the Date field.
```

If I mix them:

```
Query query = new Query("Invoice", key).addSort("Date", Query.SortDirection.ASCENDING):
//This doesn't work, and it is what I want;to retrieve the entities with the specific key and sorted
```

by a field (doesn't matter right know).

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  A key identifies a single entity, so if you retrieve the entity with a specific key, you will only get one entity.  There would be no need to sort.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not completely sure about that but I insert plenty entities in datastore with same key and the first query ("Invoice",  key)  returns all these entities,  not only one.  The solution would be to create a field that stores the user nick and get the entities with a filter for that nick and a sort?  Here is the official example: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore that uses Query query = new Query("Greeting", guestbookKey).addSort("date", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING); Thank you!!

Comment: My mistake.  I guess the "key" is the parent key.  Yes, this should work.  You might want to check the way your indexes are set up.

Comment: What do you mean about "indexes"? I think my code is not wrong at all, is the same example as the official one, so I'm very confused about what doing now because if with "key" returns the right entities, why doesn't it sort them? I've tried to get the "key" entities with a filter searching by "__key__", and it doesn't work neither. Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig

Comment: Thanks. So, the solution wolud be to create my own index to extract the entities with the "key" ordered? I'll try as soon as possible. I'll tell you the result. Thanks again.